# How do I get Feature orders from xgboost pickle model

Tags: python, xgboost

I am trying to get predictions using my xgboost pickle model using the new data but getting the error "ValueError: Feature shape mismatch"

The reason for this is I need to pass the feature names exactly in the same order model was built. For that I am using the following code but it's not working:-

```
    feature_order= model_pkl.get_booster().feature_names
    X_new = X_new[feature_order]
    Y_static = model_pkl.predict(X_new)
```

feature_order is returning "None" it was working in the xgboost version 1.1.1. But Now I am using the xgboost version 1.4.2.

Can you guys please help me in getting the feature order from my xgboost pickle model? So that I can pass my data also in the same order and not run into the error?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
feature_order= model_pkl.feature_names
```

Comment: I have tried it but getting: AttributeError: 'XGBRegressor' object has no attribute 'feature_names'

Comment: Sorry, just checked your version of Xgboost. Mine is 1.3.1

Comment: I tried on version 1.4.2. Works fine for me